# Ternary Search Tree

Tags: c++, tree, ternary-tree, ternary-search-tree

```
struct Ternary {

    char current;
    bool wordend;
    Ternary* left;
    Ternary* mid;
    Ternary* right;
    Ternary(char c='@',Ternary* l=NULL, Ternary* m=NULL, Ternary* r=NULL,bool end=false)
    {
        wordend=end;
        current=c;
        left=l;
        mid=m;
        right=r;
    }
};

void add(Ternary* t, string s, int i) {

    if (t == NULL) {
        Ternary* temp = new Ternary(s[i],NULL,NULL,NULL,false);
        t=temp;
    }

    if (s[i] < t->current) {
        add(t->left,s,i);
    }
    else if (s[i] > t->current) {
        add(t->right,s,i);
    }
    else
    {
        if ( i + 1 == s.length()) {
            t->wordend = true;
        }
        else
        {
            add(t->mid,s,i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

When I add sequence of words using `add()` the string are getting printed inside 
`if(t==NULL)` segment but tree isn't getting formed i.e nodes are not getting linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
t=temp;
```

This line has no effect outside of the `add()` function. The caller's pointer is not updated.

You could change your function to return a `Ternary*` (return `t` in this case at the end of it), and change the call sites to:

```
Ternary *tree = 0;
tree = add(tree, "hello", 1);
tree = add(tree, "bye", 1);
...
```

Comment: or declare argument as add(Ternary** t, string s, int i) and then do *t = temp

Comment: Instead of using temp, I also tried the following statement 
t=new Ternary(s[i]);

And if i use tree = ... then i m losing my root node of the tree

Comment: @Pratik: without changing anything in your code except putting `return t;` at the end of `add()` and using `add` as I indicated, you won't lose anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little trick will do:

Replace:

```
void add(Ternary* t, string s, int i)
```

With:

```
void add(Ternary*& t, string s, int i)
```

That's cleaner than passing and then reading output like this:

```
tree = add(tree, "bye", 1);
```

When in C++, make use of their references :) In C you would change the function signature to:

```
void add(Ternary** t, string s, int i)
```

and remember to correct `t` in relevant places.

Well, C++ is clearly cleaner :)